# WPF. MVVM. Add child to grid contained in dataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to use a dataTemplate to show a video source from four different cameras. My datatemplate is something like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MultiViewTemplate">
    <Grid x:Name="MultiViewGrid" ShowGridLines="True" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="GridVideo1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Image x:Name="imageMultiVideoStreaming1" Margin="1" Source="/app;component/Images/No_image_available.png" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="GridVideo2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Image x:Name="imageMultiVideoStreaming2" Margin="1" Source="/app;component/Images/No_image_available.png" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="GridVideo3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Image x:Name="imageMultiVideoStreaming3" Margin="1" Source="/app;component/Images/No_image_available.png" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="GridVideo4" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Image x:Name="imageMultiVideoStreaming4" Margin="1" Source="/app;component/Images/No_image_available.png" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

...

<Grid x:name"MainGrid" >
   <ContentControl x:Name="CameraContainer" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate=Value="{StaticResource MultiViewTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

At the beginning, when I run the application, every grid should show the image No_image_avaiable.png. It works correcty. After that, I try to connect with the cameras and each video source should be shown in GridVideo1, GridVideo2...

If I do this in code-behind I can see the video from camera 1...

```
MainGrid.Children.Add(VideoStreamingGrid1)
```

but I would like to do something like this:

```
    ...GridVideo1.Children.Add(VideoStreamingGrid1)
    ...GridVideo2.Children.Add(VideoStreamingGrid2)
    ...GridVideo3.Children.Add(VideoStreamingGrid3)
    ...GridVideo4.Children.Add(VideoStreamingGrid4)
```

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Try doing something like `(CameraContainer.Template.FindName("GridVideo1", CameraContainer) as Grid).Children.Add(VideoStreamingGrid1)`.

Comment: The mvvm-way would be to not create any controls in code behind. Afaik you can use the output of most video-apis as Imagesource somehow, maybe with a WritableBitmap in your code-behind?

Comment: Thanks @user1672994, I've tried to do that but (CameraContainer.Template.FindName("GridVideo1", CameraContainer) as Grid) is null ever. Your approach is good, I think is the right way and I'm trying to know why the result is null.